# Changing the {{ URL::to('home'); }} in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Here is my urlto in laravel

```
{{ URL::to('forgot'); }}
```

It will point as `mysite.com/forgot`

How can i insert the value here

i.e.,

```
$value = '1';
{{ URL::to('forgot'); }}
```

And it should point `mysite.com/1/forgot`

How can i insert the value of `$value` before the `forgot`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should [concatenate](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.concat.php) your `$value` before your url

i.e.,

```
$value = '1';

{{ URL::to($value.'/forgot/'); }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use named [routes](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing) with parameters.

Example route:

```
Route::get('{value}/forgot', array('as' => 'forgot', function($value = null)
{
    return "My value: " . $value;
}));
```

Now building your URL:

```
{{ route('forgot', 1); }}
```

Comment: i am just asking in building the link in blade, where i don't want to have anything in route

Comment: Your rote is defined elsewhere (in PHP). In blade you only use route() helper function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use like this check the documentation [**Documentation Here**](http://laravel.io/forum/03-07-2014-get-multiple-variables-from-url-and-pass-them-to-controller)

```
$value = '1';
{{ URL::to($value.'/forgot'); }}
```

Answer (score 0):

one way is to add a variable to your route
an example here my route is 
Route::get('/user/{id}'
then at the destination if i call $id, i get the value that was entered in id.
so if i put /user/1 , $id =1.
this can be a issue however if there is nothing. you need to include code to handle if the $id has no value. another way to do it is
return View::make('searchresults', compact('challenges', 'ideas','users'));
here i have sent arrays with search results, and on the page searchresults if i call $ideas i get that array, this will also work with strings i believe.